# How to parse xml xpath into list python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I'm trying to get values of  in to a list. I need to get a list with this values new_values = ['a','b'] using xpath

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parse = ET.parse('xml.xml')
[ record.find('events').text for record in parse.findall('.configuration/system/') ]
```

xml.xml file

```
<rpc-reply>
    <configuration>
            <system>
                <preference>
                    <events>a</events>
                    <events>b</events>                    
                </preference>
            </system>
    </configuration>
</rpc-reply>
```

The output of my python code is a list only with one value - ['a'], but i need a list with a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close. You just need to use `findall('events')` and iterate it to get all values.

**Ex:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parse = ET.parse('xml.xml')
print([ events.text for record in parse.findall('.configuration/system/') for events in record.findall('events')])
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

Optimized to a single `.findall()` call:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('input.xml').getroot()
events = [e.text for e in root.findall('configuration/system//events')]

print(events)
```

- `configuration/system//events` - relative xpath to `events` element(s)

The output:

```
['a', 'b']
```